# How to pass a user name that contain backslash (\) to jcifs smb?

Tags: java, smb, jcifs

I have been giving a user name that contain a backslash () and from windows I can access the folders in the server via file explorer. but when I try to connect via java to that server it consider the part before the slash as domain name and the part after as user name.

ex: 
username = "Hello\world"
it will give me that user "world" do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem it's the escape character "\". You can escape the escape character.

```
username = "Hello\\world";
or
username = "Hello\world".replace("\\","\\\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `\` character is an escape character. If you want to include the backslash, you need to do `\\`. Normally, if the string isn't defined in the code directly (for example you enter it via a text box), then the backslash normally gets included. Normally that character helps you to write things you literally want in the string, like a quotationmark. It ends the string, but if you do `\"`, it gets handled as a part of that string